# How can test a function that gets data from DB in a Laravel 5 package?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm working on a Laravel 5 package, and writing tests I'm trying to test a function that gets datas from DB.

```
public function getPhotoDatasFromDb()
{
    $ret = GalleryImage::get()->keyBy('file_name');
    return $ret;
}
```

The returned values should be in this format:

```
Collection {#416 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "IMG_1979.jpg" => GalleryImage {#423 ▼}
        "alt_text" => "example alt text"
        "description" => "lorem ipsum"
    "IMG_1980.jpg" => GalleryImage {#424 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I had already experiences with testing database testing in other Laravel applications.

**My question is:** since I'm writing a package, and in the dev environment I don't have an instance of the DB I'm wondering what is the best approach to test it?

If can help to have a wider picture, the database table gets created in the application trough this migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGalleryImagesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gallery_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('file_name')->unique();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('alt')->nullable();
            $table->string('video_link')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('gallery_images');
    }
}
```

And this is the model associated

```
<?php

namespace DavideCasiraghi\ResponsiveGallery;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryImage extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'file_name', 'description', 'alt', 'video_link',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to test that the `get()` method works as expected, or are you trying to test that your code saves the expected data to the database?

Comment: Thank you for your question, it helped me to get some clarity. I need to test that the get() method works as aspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I post it in case it can be helpful for somebody else.

This is my test:

```
    /** @test */
    public function it_gets_photos_from_db()
    {
        $gallery = new ResponsiveGalleryFactory();
        $dbImageDatas = $gallery->getPhotoDatasFromDb();
        $this->assertStringContainsString($dbImageDatas['DSC_9470.jpg']->description, 'Photo description');
    }
```

To make it work I had to configure the DB in the beginning of the testing class:

```
    /**
     * Create the tables this model needs for testing.
     */
    public static function setUpBeforeClass() : void
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule;

        $capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix' => '',
        ]);

        $capsule->setAsGlobal();
        $capsule->bootEloquent();

        Capsule::schema()->create('gallery_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('file_name')->unique();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('alt')->nullable();
            $table->string('video_link')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Model::unguard();

        GalleryImage::create([
            'file_name' => 'DSC_9470.jpg',
            'description' => 'Photo description',
            'alt_text' => 'Photo alt text',
            'video_link' => 'https://www.youtube.com/fsda234',
        ]);
    }
```